# What is the FQL equivalent of the Graph 'type' field from a /feed call?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been using the graph to obtain feed / post information for pages, but have started to use FQL instead as I needed to sort by updated_time rather than the standard created_time sort returned by the graph.

I am using the stream table in FQL and I can get all the information from this I require except the equivalent of the 'type' field (i.e. Status, Link, Photo, Video etc).

When I add type into the fields list for the FQL, I get a int value back (or null) which seems to roughly translate to 46 => page status, 56 => user status, 80 => link ... etc but this field is not documented and this value does not seem to be fully consistent. I've seen a user status be equal to 56 or 237, but not sure what the context difference is to make them change.

The FQL I'm using is:

```
"SELECT post_id, type,  message, description, comments, likes, created_time, updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 40796308305 ORDER BY updated_time DESC" which I'm viewing through the Graph API Explorer /fql?q=
```

I can get the type information by storing up the ids and making an additional graph call such as "`?ids=12345,23456,34567&fields=type`" but the goal is to get this in the same call.
Does anybody know how / if this can be achieved?

Many Thanks

Comment: I've got some old code in a project I was handed that also queries the type column from stream.  I'd like to use this to be able to then query page, user, and event tables to load the appropriate object that hosts the stream item.  I'm a little worried that Facebook might be deprecating that column since I cannot find "type" in their newly updated reference materials at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Comment: The answer to this question is no where to be found in Facebook's dev documentation. I'd like to know the answer to this as well. It would be nice if anyone from Facebook could address this.

Comment: A bug for this issue: [bug link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223855374358566)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was acknowledged as a bug. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223855374358566

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've subscribed to the bug report.